# Append extras informations to Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to customize Serie (in a simple way, and DataFrame by the way :p) from pandas to append extras informations on the display and in the plots? A great thing will be to have the possibility to append informations like "unit", "origin" or anything relevant for the user that will not be lost during computations, like the "name" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is not an easy way to maintain metadata on pandas objects across computations.

Maintaining metadata has been an open discussion on github for some time now but we haven't had to time code it up.

We'd welcome any additional feedback you have (see pandas on github) and would love to accept a pull-request if you're interested in rolling your own.